# Using Express.js's res.send() with async.each

Tags: express, asynchronous, async.js

```
async1.each(arr, function(arrayMember) {    
  orders.where('name', arrayMember).fetch({withRelated: ['allOrders']}).
  then(function(dd2, callback) {
    dd2 = dd2.toJSON();
    var sendMemberOrder = {};
    sendMemberOrder.name = dd2.name;
    sendMemberOrder.lastOrder = dd2.allOrders.length;
    res.send(sendMemberOrder);
  });
}, function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log("err");
  }
});
```

I'm trying to use Express's res.send() feature but given that I'm using async.each, I'm getting

> headers already sent

error.

How can I pass the result of each iteration as an array when a request is being made?

Comment: Could you please show us the whole middleware, incluing the `res.send` part?

Comment: I edited my question. If I try this way, I get an error. How can I arrange my async function so I can send everything via res.send() to the browser when it's completed?

Comment: You want it to be a JSON array of `sendMemberOrders`? Do you need a streaming solution or is it sufficient to hold the data in memory until it gets sent?

Comment: It's a small chunk of data, contains 200 words only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already use promises here, I would like to doscourage you from using async.js here. Your code is broken anyway as it does not call callback at all, and the callback parameter is declared on the wrong function. Instead you could try this:

```
app.get(your_route, function(req, res, next) {
  // obtain arr
  Promise.all(arr.map(function(arrayMember) {
    return orders.where('name', arrayMember)
    .fetch({withRelated: ['allOrders']})
    .then(function(dd2) {
      dd2 = dd2.toJSON();
      return {
        name: dd2.name,
        lastOrder: dd2.allOrders.length
      };
    });
  })).then(function(resultData) {
    res.send(resultData);
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
    next(err);
  });
});
```